# MFC CTabCtrl how to add a close button for a tab

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I'm using a CTabCtrl in my MFC Dialog Based application. The problem I'm having is that I'm adding tabs in runtime and I can't add a close button for the tabs to close. How can I achieve this? Can't I achieve this using CTabCtrl?. Is there any other way to get this done??..

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use CMFCTabCtrl instead, you could call the [CMFCTabCtrl::EnableActiveTabCloseButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982543%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, which would add the close button to the active tab.